# Where is the Preview link?

Tags: support

I can't see the `Preview` link, on the left of `help` link.

Maybe he is displayed in another area  ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand.
To get this privilege now we must earn 500 reputation.

That was not the case before because I could see this link and I don't have 500 reputation yet.